# Can't get a command prompt window to show when testing a UAC batch file on startup

Tags: windows-8.1, batch, uac, windows-task-scheduler

Most of the questions relating to this seem to be centered on *hiding* the command prompt window when running a batch file at startup.  I seem to be having the opposite problem.

I'm trying to run a batch file on startup as an administrator, and without having to click through the UAC prompt.  I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/make-vista-launch-uac-restricted-programs-at-startup-with-task-scheduler/), and have set up a scheduled task to invoke a batch file.  The thing is, I cannot get a command prompt to start and remain open.  If I have a command line such as:

```
cmd /c "C:\Users\JoeBloggs\Batch\BackgroundBatchTask.bat"
```

and I run it from `Start/Run`, it opens a command window and invokes the batch file, which is what I want (`BackgroundBatchTask.bat` is a batch file that never exits).  If I create a task to be run at startup with highest privileges and use the same command line, when I test it by right-clicking on the task and selecting "run", I see the task start in the task manager, but there is no window.  What could my problem be? (and yes, the `hidden` checkbox is not checked).

Comment: is your account  standard user account and no admin account? here Windows runs the cmd in a new session and so you can't see it

Comment: Thanks @magicandre1981.  The account is an admin one.  I must confess I am a bit hazy (well a *lot* hazy actually) on the difference between running an application with admin privileges, and running an application when logged in as an administrator.  As I want to run this task at startup - at which time presumably no-one is logged in - maybe that is affecting how Windows presents the application when it is started from the "Run" context menu of the scheduled tasks.

Comment: yes, this is your issue. Run it at logon of your admin user, but no at **start**

Comment: Ok, but what if I want the task to be started on starting windows? Do I need to use `runas` in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You could you use the run key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

create an entry:

```
MyBatch = (REG_SZ) 'cmd /c "C:\Users\JoeBloggs\Batch\BackgroundBatchTask.bat"'
```

Comment: this won't work.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652246/why-application-that-require-administrative-privileges-cannot-run-automatically).